# Selecting between NoSQL and SQL databases for AWS Calendar API

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, api, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

**Application Description**

I am currently working on developing a resource scheduling and management application.  It's essentially a calendar application with the ability to book specific items (cars or people for 1-on-1 appointments).  Users will be able to schedule resources, keep record of their past and future scheduled periods.

**Question**

I have done extensive development in the past using MySQL databases, so that tends to be my comfort zone.  I'm developing the API for this application using AWS API Gateway and Lamdas with Node.JS and am a newbie to all of these technologies.

I was hoping for some guidance on ***whether a calendar style application lends itself well to NoSQL or if going the SQL is my best bet***.  Below are the thoughts that I have had so far about the application.

**Pros of SQL:**

1. I can query data any way I want
2. I'm comfortable and familiar with it
3. Allows easy joins between the users and the events that they create

**Pros of NoSQL:**

1. Currently the data model for the bookable resources is small, but I intend on adding fields as the application starts to come together
2. Most AWS Lambda documentation revolves around the use of DynamoDB
3. Scalability (obviously)

Comment: I think either solution could work for your application, and this question is asking for an opinion (or perhaps a recommendation).

Comment: You would be correct that I am looking for a recommendation from someone who is familiar with NoSQL and it's limitations.  Is DynamoDB significantly better suited for building an API?  I guess, I'm also unsure if all of this data should be in one table or split between multiple.